# Make Hashtable immutable

Tags: c#, hashtable, overriding, immutability

How do I make a derived class from Hashtable, objects of which can be added, but cannot be removed or replaced?

What do I have to override and particularly how do I override the [] operator?

Comment: Any reason why you want to use Hashtable instead of the generic collections?

Comment: The only reason being I don't have any reasonable knowledge about available collections in C#, so I just use Hashtable whenever I need string->object indexer.

Comment: Actually, I am adding two different types to the Hashtable, that's why I'm not using generic collections.

Comment: You should still use the generic classes. You can even use Dictionary<object,object> if you like to get the same key and value types as a HashTable, but usually you can be a bit more specific about the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a minimum, you should override `Clear`, `Remove`, the property `Values` and the indexer `Item`. You can override the indexer `Item` using the syntax:

```
public override this[object key] {
    get { // get implementation }
    set { // set implementation }
}
```

You need to override `Clear` so that a user can't clear the hashtable. You need to override `Remove` so that a user can't remove entires from the hashtable. You need to override `Values` because a user could use the `ICollection` that is returned to modify the values in the hashtable. You need to override `Item` for a similar reason.

Comment: Thanks. I've just implemented Add and indexer, and used composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Note that this is only valid if deriving from HashTable. If you derive from Dictionary there is at least three more methods that you have to shadow.

Comment: @HeavyWave: Note that I answered your question, however others have done an outstanding job of explaining why you shouldn't do this. In particular, you are violating the Liskov Substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). (For example, calling `Clear` and then `Count` on a `Hashtable` will produce the value zero, but calling `Clear` and then `Count` on your derived class will not.)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of deriving from the Dictionary (which you should use rather than a HashTable), you should probably encapsulate it in this case.

The Dictionary has a lot of methods that allow changing the collection, it's easier to make it a private member, and then just implement the methods to add and access items.

Something like:

```
public class StickyDictionary<Key, Value> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>{

   private Dictionary<Key, Value> _colleciton;

   public StickyDictionary() {
      _collection = new Dictionary<Key, Value>();
   }

   public void Add(Key key, Value value) {
      _collection.Add(key, value);
   }

   public Value this[Key key] {
      get {
         return _collection[key];
      }
   }

   public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>> GetEnumerator() {
      return _collection.GetEnumerator();
   }

}
```

Comment: Right, you should not derive a class and then change its default behavior (as opposed to extending it).  If you do that, users of Dictionary may get passed a version of the ImmutableDictionary, and fail miserably because its not acting like it expects a Dictionary to act.

Comment: No, my class is not intended to be used as a collection, rather it just stores a lot of objects that are accessible in a few different ways.

Comment: Then it makes good sense to encapsulate the collection instead of deriving from it.